# AmbiguosMatchException was unhandled?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

i was coding for my listview to show its records from my database, and when i run it this error occurs, i really don't know what's the problem here:

> Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Add' can be called with
>   these arguments:     'Public Function Add(text As String) As
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem':         Argument
>   matching parameter 'text' cannot convert from 'DBNull' to 'String'.
>   'Public Function Add(item As
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem) As
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem':         Argument
>   matching parameter 'item' cannot convert from 'DBNull' to
>   'ListViewSubItem'.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form3

Public sConnection As New MySqlConnection
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=db"
        sConnection.Open()
    End If

    LoadPeople()

End Sub

Public Sub LoadPeople()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "select * from candidate"
    Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim TABLE As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(TABLE)
    End With

    For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
        With lvPeople
            .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("cid"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("cpos"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("cfname"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("cmname"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("clname"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("cyr"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("cparty"))
            End With
        End With
    Next


End Sub
End Class
```

and it's pointing on this one `.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("cpos"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that is not a `DbNull` value before adding it to the ListView. You can use a function like this

```
Private Function AddFieldValue(row As DataRow, fieldName As String) As String 
   If Not DbNull.Value.Equals(row.Item(fieldName)) Then 
      Return CStr(row.Item(fieldName)) 
   Else 
      Return Nothing 
   End If 
End Function
```

Use it in that way

```
.Add(AddFieldValue(TABLE.Rows(i), ("cpos")))
```

Comment: uhm, where should i put this again? :)

Comment: it's now running without errors, thanks! but why it is not showing any records in it? :)